# Punctuation after multiline math diagram

Tags: math-mode, punctuation, xy-pic, multline

How to place the punctuation after multiline math diagram at the last line rather than the first line as the case showed in my following code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
  \xymatrix{
  A\ar[d]\\
  B
  }{\color{red}.}
\end{gather}

\begin{equation}
  \xymatrix{
  A\ar[d]\\
  B
  }{\color{red}.}
\end{equation}

\[
  \xymatrix{
  A\ar[d]\\
  B
  }{\color{red}.}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you put it in the diagram but hide its width so B is not horizontally shifted in relation to the arrow.  Also you should center the diagram with respect to the equation number:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \vcenter{\xymatrix{
  A\ar[d]\\
  B\rlap{\ .}
  }}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I would judge how much space to put before the dot according to the surrounding text.  Nothing or `\,` might be better than what I have given.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I learned that ``rlap`` does not work in mathmode, it however works in this case.

Comment: `\rlap` is just an `\hbox` with some internal spacing.  It works fine in math mode, but its content is ordinary material, not math mode material.

Comment: @MaMing You can use `\mathrlap` when math mode.  See http://math.arizona.edu/~aprl/publications/mathclap/ for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the command `{\color{red}.}` inside the environment.

Like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
  \xymatrix{
  A\ar[d]\\
  B
  {\color{red}.}}
\end{gather}

\begin{equation}
  \xymatrix{
  A\ar[d]\\
  B
  {\color{red}.}}
\end{equation}

\[
  \xymatrix{
  A\ar[d]\\
  B
  {\color{red}.}}
\]

\end{document}
```

Gives the result:

[image]

Comment: This will change $B$ to $B.$, which is not strictly that I want.

Comment: See Andrews suggestion, use `\rlap` to *hide* it from alignment